# cannot upload images into database and application(fileuploader js file)? fileuploader js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload

My requirement is i have to update images in both database and application using fileuploaderjs file. but i am to upload either in application or database. below is my code ,please help me.and my database with name Images have two columns namely imagename,image.actually once we read stream data the content present in that becoming null. so i cannot able to use further that stream.. that's why i am not able to upload both in database and application folder.i am able to upload either in database or application folder.

**.cshtml**

```
<link href="../../Content/fileuploader.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="../../Scripts/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('in');
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({

        // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
        action: '/Home/DigitalAssetsFileUpload?fileType=image',

        template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
            '<ul  class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
            '<a class="qq-upload-button"  >Upload a file</a>' +
              '</div>',
        multiple: false,
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif'],
        debug: true,
        onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {

                alert('inserted');

        }
    });

 });



 </script>
 <div style="margin: -5px 0pt 4px 54px; position: relative; position: relative;">
 <div id="file-uploader-demo1" style="text-align: right; width: 0px; padding-left:   
 157px;">
</div>
  </div>







**controller class** 


 this is controller which i have .


   public void DigitalAssetsFileUpload(string recFileType = "image")
    {
        long fileSizeInBytes = 0;
        string fileType = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["fileType"];
         string phyicalFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images");
         string uploadedFileName = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
        uploadedFileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uploadedFileName);





        string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(uploadedFileName);
        Stream inputstream = null;

        inputstream = HttpContext.Request.InputStream;


        string storagePath = phyicalFilePath;
        if (!Directory.Exists(storagePath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(storagePath);
        }
        string pFilePath = storagePath + "\\" +uploadedFileName;
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(pFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);





        if (inputstream == null)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application", "stream is null");
            throw new NullReferenceException("stream is null");
        }
        fileSizeInBytes = inputstream.Length;

        using (fileStream)
        {
            using (inputstream)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                int bytesRead;

                while ((bytesRead = inputstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

            }
        }

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(inputstream);

        byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((Int32)inputstream.Length);

        string constr = "data source=localhost; initial catalog=sample; persist security    
        info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Insert_Images", con);
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = data;
        com.Parameters.Add("@imagename", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = uploadedFileName;
        con.Open();
        int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

       }


  plz suggest any answer to me
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery library must be referenced before any plugin. And it must be reference only once.
Change order of `script` tags as below and remove `jquery-1.7.1.js` file reference

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/fileuploader.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Look at this lines in your code:

```
        using (inputstream)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            int bytesRead;

            while ((bytesRead = inputstream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

        }
```

Here you writing data from the input stream into file and after that disposing input stream.
You need to dispose input stream after you save data into all locations. 
And after each save you must set position in input stream to beginning either calling `inputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` or setting position explicitly: `inputStream.Position = 0;`

Comment: thanks for your comment.. but it does not solve my issue

Comment: it uploading only in application folder.not  database. in  database image data is null